# NE Attribute editor not honouring custom selection

Tags: arcobjects

I have an application based on [Network Engineer](http://www.telcordia.com/products/network_eng/index.html) & [ArcObjects](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisengine/java/doc/b0a96bd8-fc78-4573-9a70-e108cf6a4580.htm).

A part of the functionality requires users to draw a rectangle an select features. It should "add" to the current selection.

I am using a custom selection method (incorporating *QueryFilter* & *IFeatureSelection*) and selecting features in the layers. Once I am done with the selection, I open the NE Attribute Editor to see the properties of selected records, but I don't see any of the newly selected features!

I tried calling the *SelectionChanged()* and *MakePermanent()* methods and even refreshed the selection but nothing helps...

Any ideas?

PS: I have yet not tried the built-in commands. Will need some time to check if it works (I am sure it will as it is "built-in", but I don't see a reason why the feature selection does not work).

Comment: OK, as expected the NE attribute editor works fine with the built-in selection tools. Now I am even more puzzled than before as to why this is not working...